# Pullback of Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, pullback

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0 and let $\varphi:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{f}$ and $\psi:\mathfrak{h}\rightarrow\mathfrak{f}$ be maps of Lie algebras. Is there a reference showing that the pullback (in the category of Lie $k$-algebras) of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ along these maps is given by the following formula

> $\mathfrak{g}\times_\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{h}=\{(x,y)\in\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{h}\mid \varphi(x)=\psi(y)\}$

EDIT: Just to be extra clear. I do know how to prove it, but I cannot find a place in the literature where this is proved or stated and I was wondering if you knew of one.

Comment: It is trivial and holds for every algebraic category: the forgetful functor creates limits. This statement can be found in texts on universal algebra or category theory.

Comment: If you are looking for a citation for the purposes of off-loading the proof, then it might actually be better *not* to have the reader chase a reference just so that they end up discovering you directed them to something very simple that they could have done in the time it took to find the reference.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: I gave some reference in my answer, but I agree. This might be one of those cases where writing something like "it is well-known that..", "recall that..", or "it is easy to see that.." is better than giving any detail or a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference for pullbacks for modules over a ring: Proposition 5.11, p.222 in "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" by Rotman. For Lie $k$-algebras (or just $k$-algebras), you could refer to this and say the same construction/proof works.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the existence of free Lie algebras. More precisely, the forgetful functor $U: \mathbf{Lie}_k \to \mathbf{Vect}_k$ has a left adjoint $F$ which takes $V$ to the free Lie algebra on $V$. Hence, $U$ preserves limits. This fact has many references, c.f. MacLane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, §V.5.

Comment: Though correct, this answer seems unnecessarily complicated. One can easily verify directly that the OP's proposed pullback has the required universal property.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I am afraid my question was a bit misleading. I do know how to prove it. I was wondering if this fact can be found anywhere in the literature, maybe as an exercise in a book? I could not find a reference by googling it. I am specifically looking for a place in the literature where this is proved or at least stated.

Comment: @user15160811 I don't know offhand a reference for this fact specifically about Lie algebras, but I'd expect textbooks on universal algebra to prove this in much greater generality --- for arbitrary varieties of algebras.

Comment: @user15160811 I have added a reference to the general statement about adjoint functors and limits. Hopefully this may do.

Comment: @AndreasBlass does the general proof use the existence of free algebras?

Comment: Free algebras are not necessary.

Comment: Martin is right; the existence of free algebras isn't needed for this result.  But if you already know for other reasons (not the adjoint functor theorem) that free algebras exist then they can be used as in your answer (except that in general one would take the underlying set functor, not the underlying vector-space functor, since vector spaces might not be involved in the general case).